# Trigger a specific button and run some code with Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I wanted to run some code via PrestanShop when a specific button is pressed, before/after the designed action is happened.It's not alter the designed action, just is send some notification to an external system (notify the 3-rd party that we have a new sale and maybe with sales detalis: product, prices, etc)

To be more specific the action is finish a sale(or make an order) when click the related button.

I read something related (hooks and module) but maybe someone have the same issue then any help is appreciated.(even with no code, but good hints)
Maybe what hook is to be triggered here or some hints how to alter the code using PS-standards.
(light way and not just adding some php code to alter in the hard way the core)

[image]

Note: language on interface is romanian and the action is when a sale is post into the system (became an order, payments is not relevant/order_status).

[image]

Thank you,
Traian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `actionValidateOrder` and make your call to your 3rd party in this function.
This hook is called here :

```
classes/PaymentModule.php line 716
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do not have time to test it now and it's sound a fair logical answer, so for the moment I could consider the answer as solution.

Comment: I could confirm now that your answer is accurate. Thank you !